Conditions on Coefficients for a first Order ODE
Just want some expert advice, since I refuse to let ChatGPT become my math tutor. Consider the ODE: 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{Ax+By+C}{Dx+Ey+F}
$$
Assume that $B\neq-D$, i.e., that the equation is not exact. Assume $\mu$ is an integrating factor which makes the above equation exact.
If we want to find $\mu$ such that $\mu$ is a function of strictly $x$ or strictly $y$, then then what conditions would have to be imposed on the coefficients $A,B,C,D,E,F$ in order for this to be possible? Also, can we find a general solution for y(x)?
So far, I have found that if $\mu=\mu(x)$, then $E$ must be $0$, and I got:
$$
\mu(x)=K|x+F/D|^{-(B/D+1)}
$$
(I would really appreciate if some pro checked this, I did my best). Now after obtaining $\mu(x)$, I wanted to solve for $y(x)$ by multiplying
$$
(Ax+By+C)dx - (Dx+F)dy = 0
$$
by $\mu(x)$, but I can't see how to separate variables after doing this. Any tips?

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{Ax+By+C}{Dx+Ey+F}
$$
You can translate it by substituting $x=u+h$ and $y=v+k$ where $h,k$ are obtained from solving these two $Ah+By+C$ and $Dh+Ek+F$.
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{A(u+h)+B(v+k)+C}{D(u+h)+E(v+k)+F}$$
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{Au+Bv+(Ah+Bk+C)}{Du+Ev+(Dh+Ek+F)}$$
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{Au+Bv}{Du+Ev}$$
Plug $u=tv$ and proceed ||
note:
constants : $A,B,C,D,E,F,h,k$,
variables : $x,y,t,u,v$, The restrictions on the coefficients can be brought out from the fact that those two equations give a unique solution and so on. By this we have homogenized it.

That works, seems like you pulled that substitution out of nowhere. But thank you!

Were you interested in a specific example that led you to ask this generalized non-homogeneous DE?

Not in particular, I just thought this would generalize different cases for integrating factors and exact equations
